# Windows explorer freezes when trying to transfer files from mobile

Tags: windows, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I tried to transfer files (of extension PPT, DOC, MP4 and so on) from my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 to my laptop (Windows 10; tried on two laptops from Dell and Lenovo). Once  I plug the USB cable I can see both device storage and card storage and I can sometimes (let's say 1 out of 3) browse the folder. When I try to copy the file from that mobile folder into my laptop mobile, it works 1 out of 10 times! Most of the time explorer freezes or it starts to browse the folder (i.e. the path bar is progressing but never ends).

I installed USB drivers on my laptop. I even installed Kies but then Kies itself launches explorer and loops.

Please do not tell me to use Wi-Fi as I am in a hotel with very poor connection and I am using my 4G phone to actually download files and then (I thought that would be easy) I was thinking to transfer those files to my laptop through USB cable.

Actually, what is working is: I plug the cable, I go into the folder and select the file. Then I unplug the cable but I keep the explorer opened.
Then I plug again and at that time I right-click, copy the selected file and then I am able to paste it in a laptop folder. Yes, that is working. But I would not do that for all the files I need to transfer.

There should be a simple way, right?

Comment: Such unplugging and re-connecting will sooner or later lead to data corruption. Get a new USB cable instead of wearing out the solder joints in your charging connector. NOT the cheapes cable you find. Get quality cables!

Comment: @svin83 I have the exact same problem. The cable I'm using is the original cable Samsung gave me, I don't know what a better cable is.

Comment: @Gqqnbig If your cable is wonky and you're unsure: Go to any reputable local store that sells electronics. Ask for a medium-to-high quality USB cable that fits your phone and supports data transfers and fast charging. Then put the wonky cable somewhere in case you lose the new cable.

Comment: @Gqqnbig Also: If you get a cable and you're satisfied with it, then go back to the same store and get one more exactly like it.... Cables tend to wear out over time...